# How to fix "Cannot resolve symbol 'app' " in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat

Android studio is showing errors on every line that is related to support library. And on rebuilding the project it says:

Android resource linking failed.

I've tried following:

1. clean/rebuild
2. Invaidate caches/Restart
3. Uninstall/Reinstall Android Studio

My build.gradle(app) is Following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.androphobia.fyp.spreadknowledge"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

styles.xml is as Following:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Image of styles.xml in project is as:
[image: styles.xml]

Image of results on rebuilding project:
[image: Image of results on rebuilding project]

Comment: add error code as text not image

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955002/cannot-resolve-symbol-app

Comment: @Basi thanks for replying 
I added the image because in code it will not be possible to show errors that android studio shows on rebuilding the project.

Comment: @GovindParashar I have already read that answer but unfortunately did not work for me

Comment: @RanaHamzaKhursheed check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49745282/4649110) for getting build error log

Comment: Delete  build folder under app and make sure you didn't add some incomplete code somewhere in the activity, adapter or anywhere else.

Comment: @Jyot deleted the build folder and sure there is no error in any class except mentioned above but nothing changed same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migrating to **Android-X** resolved the issue.

Go to:

**Refactor** --> **Migrate to AndroidX**

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding this dependency here :

```
 implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"
```

Comment: can you pass the style code in the question please ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870881/cant-find-theme-appcompat-light-for-new-android-actionbar-support

And also try this link

Comment: check now the question

Comment: type `parent="android:Theme.Light"` this instead of your code

Comment: Replacing with     parent="android:Theme.Light"  remove error on only specific line because I think errors are due to appcompat library.

Comment: well I would to like @Sejpal Pavan says , but also , I would suggest to migrate to Android x if it is a new project

Answer (score 0):

remove this two dependency,

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

downgrade to 27 and check,or check sdk 28 is installed

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Close the Android Studio 
2. Delete the .AndroidStudio3.3 folder from File System
3. start Android Studio after that .AndroidStudio3.3 Folder Recreated Automaticall then 
   Your Error will be solved
```

Comment: Problem is resolved thanks  for you contribution. I upgraded to AndroidX.

Comment: Yoo bro !!  keep it up.

Answer (score 0):

Issue related **[CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView)** version and your project.

In Your project your support library version `28.0.0 (pre-androidx`) and  **CircleImageView** `version 3` which is running **androidx** version.

so you have to **upgrade your project androidx**  or **downgrade circleImageView version** to `2.x`

Answer (score 0):

File > Invalidate caches/Restart

Worked for me.